# Validate string from HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation

I need a PHP form (a single text/number field only) that will pass the user to a specific address, but only if the first 4 digits of the code entered into the form match 1234 (example). I understand basic forms, but I'm stumped a bit and what was suggested to me previously doesn't seem to work quite right.

Objective: For example ... when the user enters "**1234**5678909876" into the form, they will be taken to http://sample.web, otherwise the page simply refreshes with a statement "Incorrect code"

Here's what I have thus far thanks to user "jfhs" ...

```
<?php
$valid_code = '3471';
$ok = true;
if (isset($_POST['code']) && is_string($_POST['code'])) {
    if (substr($_POST['code'], -strlen($valid_code)) === $valid_code) {
        header('Location: http://sample.web/');     
        die();
    }
    $ok = false;
}
?>
<!-- some html here-->
<?php if (!$ok):?>
    <p style="color:red">Wrong code</p>
<?php endif;?>
<form method="post">
    <input name="code">
    <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

Currently, the code works only when the first 4 numbers are entered (only). I need it to work with a series of numbers like in the description and example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not sure why you are checking that it is a string... seems overkill. You do not really give an example of what you're trying to have it do, but I assume from the title, you want it to examine the last 4 digits, and it is looking at the first 4. Is that correct?

Comment: From php.net for substr: `$rest = substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef"`

Comment: [Read up on the `substr` function](http://php.net/manual/it/function.substr.php). `$rest = substr($_POST['code'],0,4);` should do the trick. (Or of course the fancier way proposed by @lshas which takes the actual length of the code into account in case you decide to change the length of the coder later on)

Comment: Yes, sorry all, the title is incorrect. I am looking for the first four digits. The title and current code I gave was a carry over from my previous incorrectly formatted post/question (which is now locked). So, here I am again. THX!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$valid_code = '3471';
$ok = true;
if (isset($_POST['code']) && is_string($_POST['code'])) {
    if (substr($_POST['code'], 0, strlen($valid_code)) === $valid_code) {
        header('Location: http://sample.web/');     
        die();
    }
    $ok = false;
}
?>
<!-- some html here-->
<?php if (!$ok):?>
    <p style="color:red">Wrong code</p>
<?php endif;?>
<form method="post">
    <input name="code">
    <input type="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

This should work.
The problem with your code was that it was checking agains the ***last*** four digits of the string, while as I understand it you want to check against the 4 ***first*** digits of the string. This code should do the trick.

Your post is a little contradictory, because the title says the four last digits, but in the post it says the four first. But you have both solutions here now, the one I wrote here is for the four first ones, and the one you already have is for the four last ones.

Comment: I will give this a try see if it works as intended. Will get back to you. THX!

Answer (score 0):

```
<php
$valid_code = 1234;
$pass=false;
if (isset($_POST['code'] && substr($_POST['code'], 0, 4)  == $valid_code){
    header('Location: http://sample.web/');
    die();
}
```

So, what you should do: first, always assume that the answer is wrong. This way you only let the user pass when they passed your test (as opposed to: when they do not fail), the reason being that your test might be ill designed.
Then, all you need is to check the first characters.
Bear in mind that anything submitted via POST or GET is always a string so you can treat it like one.
You may wqant to read up a little about cross-site scripting, though.